# Ionic 2 + One Signal para Notificações

Tags: ionic2, api

Meu plugin Ionic já está integrado com Firebase e One Signal, já consigo trabalhar com login e senha e enviar as notificações.

Meu problema está em customizar as notificações.

No campo sound, eu coloco o caminho para o arquivo de tres formas e nenhuma funcionou

```
1 - <project-root>/platforms/android/res/raw/sound.ogg
2 - /platforms/android/res/raw/sound.ogg
2 - platforms/android/res/raw/sound.ogg
```

Fiz da forma que está na documentação.

https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/customize-notification-sounds

Comment: Está sendo exibido algum erro?

Comment: Oi @MarcelodeAndrade, então, a notificação é enviada para o dispositivo, mas não debuguei pelo navegador, vou fazer isso e posto o resultado.

Comment: Verique, assim fica mais fácil encontrar o problema e consequentemente a solução. Veja se a notificação é recebida tanto no aparelho quanto no navegador também.